# how to update control on one view from another view in mvvm

Tags: mvvm, dependency-injection, dependencies, prism

Hi I have three region based views in my MVVM application. I am new to MVVM and I want to update DataGrid on click on button from different view.

One view have one button and second view have datagrid. I would like to update datagrid result or bind datagrid when button on other view is pressed. I saw few post on doing it with eventService but I am not sure how. cany anyone give me some example to do as I am new so not sure. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution is to use the same ViewModel in both views:

ViewModel:

```
public class MyModel : ViewModel
{
  static myModel;
  public static MyModel Current { get { if(myModel==null) myModel=new MyModel(); return myModel; } }

  public IEnumerable<T> Data { get { ... } set { /* Notification */ }}
  public ICommand SetData {get { return new DelegateCommand(()=>Data= /* return the data */); }
}
```

Button view:

```
<Button Command={Binding SetData} />
```

DataGrid view:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Data} />
```

In the code-behind of both views, add to the constructor:
    this.DataContext = MyModel.Current;